# Passing variables from GitLab UI to child pipeline not working

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am having an issue with GitLab passing variables from parent pipeline to child pipeline. Variables declared globally are passed, but the ones specified in GitLab UI are not.

My example is like below:

parent.yml

```
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT:
      value: dev
      options:
        - "dev"
        - "staging"
        - "prod"

  stages: 
    - child
  
  deploy:
    stage: child
    trigger:
      include: child_dir/child-pipeline.yml
```

and the child_dir/child-pipeline.yml is:

```
before_script:
  - echo "$ENVIRONMENT"
  - echo "$SOME_OTHER_ENV_VARIABLES_PASSED_THROUGH_UI"
```

ENVIRONMENT -> is passed fine, value "dev" is echoed in child pipeline.
SOME_OTHER_ENV_VARIABLES_PASSED_THROUGH_UI -> is passed by GitHub UI Environment Variables - it's protected, but not masked. Nothing is echoed in child pipeline.

I have tried calling the environment variable inside of child job:

```
  deploy:
    stage: child
    variables:
      SOME_OTHER_ENV_VARIABLES_PASSED_THROUGH_UI: $SOME_OTHER_ENV_VARIABLES_PASSED_THROUGH_UI
    trigger:
      include: child_dir/child-pipeline.yml
```

but didn't work.

Does anyone has experienced such issue, or I'm missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found the issue. Variables must not be "protected". Removing "protected" checkbox from GitLab UI environment variable made it work perfectly.

Though, GitLab should maybe mention that in their documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?#pass-cicd-variables-to-a-downstream-pipeline